# rsync cronjob succeeds during the day but always fails to find the destination at night. Might my external hard-drive "go to sleep"?

Tags: cron, rsync, hard-disk, backup

NOTE: there is an easy solution to this problem (i.e., just backup your data during the day!), so this is not an urgent problem. But I have searched extensively on stack exchange and askubuntu and haven't seen this issue posted and I am a little curious if someone knows a quick fix.

I've been using a cron job to back up data on both my home and office computers to external hard drives. All works as desired on the home computer but the office computer (Dell OptiPlex running Ubuntu 22.04.3, backing up to a Western Digital usb hard drive) has a funny pathology I cannot figure out.

When I am testing the cronjob, I set the desired time, one minute to the future, wait for the clock to change, and then look and see that the job is running just fine. But then when I set the job to run in the middle of the night, the exact same job fails with the following message:

```
No such file or directory (2) "/media/hb/a993cec9-4360-4000-ad03-394b2051f0cc1"
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(791) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

So, every morning I come into work, check if the backups ran, see that they failed, do a test run to figure out why, and all works fine.  Is it at all possible that the external hard drive "goes to sleep" whenever the computer is inactive? The computer does not sleep, and I have accessed it remotely via ssh at odd hours of the night before. I never have to actively mount the drive in the morning, it seems to always be there whenever I am sitting at the computer.

My crontab looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 1 * * * /snap/bin/offlineimap -c /home/hb/snap/offlineimap/297/.offlineimaprc 
0 2 * * * /home/hb/backup_office_computer.sh daily > /home/hb/backup_daily.log 2>&1
0 3 * * 6 /home/hb/backup_office_computer.sh weekly > /home/hb/backup_weekly.log 2>&1

# -- daytime tests here
48 9 * * * /home/hb/backup_office_computer.sh weekly > /home/hb/backup_weekly.log 2>&1
```

The offlineimap job always works (so cron is OK), and the daytime test rsync job always work (so the shell script is OK), but the 2am and 3am backup jobs always fail to find the external harddrive.

The `backup_office_computer.sh` script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

WD_path="/media/hb/a993cec9-4360-4000-ad03-394b2051f0cc1"

# print start time
now=$(date)
echo "========= starting backup at: $now ========="
echo "========= running as: $(whoami) ========="

# backup home directory
rsync -aAXP --delete --exclude '*.Trash-1000' --exclude 'tmp*' --exclude '.cache' --exclude '.dbus' --exclude '.gvfs' /home/hb $WD_path/home-backup-$1

echo "========= home backup completed. Starting LSS: $now ========="

if [ "$(ls -A /media/hb/LSS)" ]; then
        # LSS is mounted (LSS is better for long-term storage than quick edits. Once a week should be enough)
        if [ $1 == "weekly" ]; then
                rsync -aAXP --delete /media/hb/LSS/* $WD_path/LSS-backup-$1/
        else
                echo "Ignoring LSS: We only back up weekly."
        fi
else
        echo "/media/hb/LSS is empty. Drive not mounted"
fi

# print end time
now=$(date)
echo "====== backup finished at at: $now ========"
```

The nightly error message about missing directory always refers to destination drive `/media/hb/a993cec9-4360-4000-ad03-394b2051f0cc1` not the other mounted drive being backed up weekly `/media/hb/LSS/`

===== UPDATE (2023/11/22) =====

Since posting I have tried ssh-ing into the office computer and within 5 minutes of walking away from the computer the external drive disappears and cannot be found via `lsblk` and thus I cannot mount it. Of course the folder and files within also disappear and cannot be seen via `ls`.

When I physically return to my computer, as soon as I touch the keyboard or mouse it starts to whir and by the time I have unlocked the screen the drive can once more be found by `lsblk` and it has automounted so all files are visible via `ls` in a familiar location.

As a test, I changed my system preferences to wait 15 minutes of inactivity, instead of 5, for the screen to dim and lock. I could then access the drive from an ssh-login 10 minutes after I left, but once more, after 15 minutes the drive disappeared and became unmountable as far as I know.

Thus, I think the external drive (Model: WD Elements 25A3 (1030)) automatically goes to sleep whenever my screen dims and locks.

I could simply disable all power saving tools on my computer, but before I try something so drastic, I am reading up on `sdparm` and `hdparm` tools for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. You could try adding something like `k=5; while ! ls /media/hb/a993...cc1 && [ $k -gt 0 ]; do k=$((k-1)); sleep 30; done` near the top, to see if that wakes up the drive, but it's a hack not a solution

Comment: @ChrisDavies The hack suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: @ChrisDavies I've implemented the hack and will update if it works. But unfortunately I won't know until tomorrow. This has been one of the most frustrating things about debugging this issue. Everything works now.

Comment: Maybe add an `set -o xtrace` in line 2 and add `--verbose` to the rsync-call, for some additional info in the logs.  If the drive is falling asleep, try waking it up with `fdisk -l` or somesuch.

Comment: I've had Western Digital drives that put themselves to sleep... as I recall I had to download some utility from W-D that disabled this *energy saving* feature.  Also re work computer: Is it administered by IT staff at your workplace?

Comment: If you logout before the cron runs, the disk may get unmounted automatically by systemd. Instead of relying on udisks automounting the disk when you login, you could add an explicit permanent mount (at a different directory) of the disk in `/etc/fstab`. (You could try that during the daytime: set a cron for lunchtime, logout before lunch.)

Comment: @meuh does systemd mount/unmount drives at user login? That could be really annoying!

Comment: I can't say for certain if logout provokes unmount, but there is a complex
mechanism whereby systemd login sessions interact with dbus, udisks2, gnome
(or other desktops), to ensure the user gets automatic access to devices,
including automounting of drives on /media/. Perhaps logout reverses some
of these for security. It is worth a quick test, as tracing how it really
works can be difficult.

Comment: @ChrisDavies No luck with the hack.  The script ran ls on the drive 5 times and failed to find it each time. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Seamus No the office computer is administered solely by me. The IT staff here grudgingly tolerates a few linux users managing their own systems.

Comment: HB, one thing you might try is to take your office computer home for the evening, and test it there?? That doesn't *eliminate* IT as the cause of course, just another data point. Seems to me it almost has to be something on your office PC.

Comment: @meuh following your advice I added a line in `/etc/fstab` to manually mount the drive (`UUID=a993cec9-4360-4000-ad03-394b2051f0cc /media/hb/a993cec9-4360-4000-ad03-394b2051f0cc ext4    defaults 0  0`) and another line to bind this to another location (`/media/hb/a993cec9-4360-4000-ad03-394b2051f0cc /media/hb/WD_backup_office none bind 0 0`).  After rebooting, I have confirmed the files are found in both specified places, and the cronjob backup successfully found the backup drive, even after I logged out of the computer before it started. So far so good.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Seamus I agree taking the computer would be a good test. Although, probably before I got that desperate, I would just accept this idiosyncratic behavior, and set the backup to run at times of the day I won't be using the computer much (e.g. lunch break, weekly meetings, etc.). Thanks though!

Comment: You have more patience than I... this would drive me absolutely nuts :Q